# MULTIPLE INSERT VALUES with INSERT into another table

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 2 tables, *events* and *event_users*:

#### Events

```
id      int  
type    int
date    date     
time    time
```

#### Event_users

```
event_id    int
user_id     int
user_role   int
...
```

*Events* can have many *event_users* (one-to-many relationship).

When I insert more than one event in the *Events* table, the query is:

```
INSERT INTO events
    (type,date,time)
VALUES
    (1,12-02-14,08:15:00),
    (1,13-02-14,08:15:00),
    (1,14-02-14,08:15:00),
    (1,15-02-14,08:15:00)
```

But at the time I know the *events* table info, I also know some of the *event_users* table info.

So, because I need the **events.id** to write the *event_users* record, how can I insert the events **and** the event_users records in one query? The database is MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL, you cannot insert into 2 tables in one statement. You can though in many statements, inside one transaction.

Comment: Thx @ypercube, could write down an example?